# .NET ChatRemoting issues

Tags: .net

Im coding a Chat App using .NET Remoting. The problem is that i want to use Invoke to edit a form (addMsg) in the client but i cant call it because i can only instantiate the superclass (in clientObject constructor) and not the subclass because its not visible for me.
I can't explain the problem very well but its explicit in the code in the comments.

Client code:

namespace DADChat
{

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private MyRemoteObject objetoServidor = null;
    private clientObject objetoCliente = null;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void sendButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string mensagem = messageBox.Text;
        string nick = nickBox.Text;

        objetoServidor.enviaMensagem(nick, mensagem);
    }

    public void addMsg(string m) //adiciona mensagem à conversa
    {
        textBox4.Text += "\r\n" + m;
    }

    private void connectButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string url = "tcp://localhost:" + portBox.Text + "/objectClientName";
        int port = Int32.Parse(portBox.Text);
        string nick = nickBox.Text;

        TcpChannel channel = new TcpChannel(port);
        ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, true);

        objetoCliente = new clientObject(this); /* i use this to pass the reference of this object so i can edit the form in the remote class */

        RemotingServices.Marshal(objetoCliente, "objectClientName", typeof(clientObject));

        objetoServidor = (MyRemoteObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(MyRemoteObject), "tcp://localhost:8096/MyRemoteObjectName");

        NovoCliente cliente = new NovoCliente();
        cliente.Nome = nick;

        objetoServidor.adicionarCliente(cliente.Nome, url, port);
        objetoServidor.printListaClientes();
    }
}
```

}

The Remote class:
namespace ChatObjects
{
    public delegate void delChat(string m);

```
public class MyRemoteObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    private List<NovoCliente> listaClientes = new List<NovoCliente>();
    public event delChat serverParaCliente;

    public string metodoOla()
    {
        return "Ola!";
    }

    public void adicionarCliente(string nome, string url,int port)
    {
        if (nome != null)
        {
            NovoCliente cliente = new NovoCliente();
            cliente.Nome = nome;
            cliente.Porto = port;
            cliente.URL = url;
            listaClientes.Add(cliente);
        }
    }

    public void printListaClientes()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listaClientes.Count; i++)
            Console.WriteLine("Cliente: " + listaClientes[i].Nome + " e a sua localização é " + listaClientes[i].Porto + "\n");
    }

    public void enviaMensagem(string nickname, string mensagem) //método responsável por receber a mensagem do utilizador e envia para o chat 
    {
        string mensagemFinal = nickname + ": " + mensagem;

       foreach (NovoCliente cliente in listaClientes)
        {
            clientObject obj = (clientObject)Activator.GetObject(typeof(clientObject), cliente.URL);
            obj.recebeMsg(mensagemFinal);
        }
    }
}

public class clientObject : MarshalByRefObject
{
    public Form f; /* the problem resides here because to call addMsg it should Form1 f and not Form */
    public clientObject(Form f)
    {
        this.f = f;
    }

     public void recebeMsg(string msg)
    {
        f.Invoke(new delChat(f.addMsg), new object[] { msg });   /* cant call addMsg */  
    }
}
public class NovoCliente
{
    private string nome;
    private int porto;
    private string url;

    public string Nome
    {
        get
        {
            return nome;
        }
        set
        {
            nome = value;
        }
    }
    public string URL
    {
        get
        {
            return url;
        }
        set
        {
            url = value;
        }
    }

    public int Porto
    {
        get
        {
            return porto;
        }
        set
        {
            porto = value;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Thank you for the help in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you set up the remote listener you need to pass its Form1 instance in. Or make it available. HAve a static on some object somewhere that has the Form1 instance. You remoting class can then read it.

Comment: could you give an exemple please?